# python : How to include third party app by cx_freeze and bdist_msi?

Tags: python, windows, installation, windows-installer

I extracted the python package as an msi file by cx_freeze and bdist_msi.
The msi file consisting only of the python package confirmed its installation and execution.
Next step, I want to include the third party windows application(ex:sqlite) in the installation file.

Is there a way to include third-party applications as cx_freeze only or another application?

- python version : 3.6.5.
- OS : windows 10

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand your question.  You could check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307934/creating-msi-with-cx-freeze-and-bdist-msi-for-pyside-app.  Alternatively apps like cx_freeze can be repackaged into a Windows Installer using a free tool such as: https://www.itninja.com/community/dell-kace-appdeploy-repackager.  cx_freeze is essentially a file dump inside the Python installation directory if i recall, so not too complex in that sense.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
My question was how to package msi file extracted by cx_freeze and another msi file.
I will try the appdeploy repackager program you recommended. 
Thanks.