# Is there any way to create MSI package of single executable exe file that is generated from pyinstaller --onefile?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-installer, exe, cx-freeze

I have created single file executable using pyinstaller for e.g **demo.exe**
let us suppose i have to create an MSI of it, how i can achieve this
i have already used INNO , AdvanceInstaller, EMCO, and few of those as well, nothing of them worked.

is there any way to create an MSI using cx_freeze, as though cx_freeze convert python application to MSI.

how i can pass .exe extension to cx_freeze, is there any variant?

**my objective** is to create an **MSI** of an executable and **hide** all the **python related files** when the package is installed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have python experience but from what I read only the demo.exe you got from pyinstaller is already an installer. So I assume you want a MSI to wrap around it?

If so, here is how to use Advanced Installer to create an MSI wrapper over one or more exe installers:

- [MSI wrapper over one or multiple EXEs](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-msi-wrapper-over-exe.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cx_freeze to create MSIs directly, a similar post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307934/creating-msi-with-cx-freeze-and-bdist-msi-for-pyside-app).
But if you already have your python script compiled to an EXE, you can [easily create a simple MSI for it](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html).